# Ubuntu Server won't start

Tags: server, startup

I just installed Ubuntu Server again. I've done that quite a few times before.

I try starting the system and get to the point where it changes the font on the screen. A little while after that the monitor flickers and I just get a black screen. After that it flickers some more and doesn't respond to anything.

The weird thing comes when I boot into recovery mode.  If I select resume boot (without even doing anything else) it resumes boot and finishes booting, giving me a shell.
It definitely isn't just a graphics problem either since SSH won't respond (after resume boot it will let me in).

I put the syslog and the output of dmesg [here](http://xyious.com/Log/putty.log). I can't distinguish between the failed startups and the successful ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5581013#5581013).

I had to add [`nomodeset`](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132) as a boot parameter to the kernel which made it work. I still get a fail on loading backup graphics device, but since i'll be using the server mostly via ssh that's not a problem.

(In short, it's likely the graphics driver fails in some way. I'm using an NVidia GT 620, which might be too new.)

Comment: again thanks to Eliah Kagan for the response. I had the exact same problem with another server as well, without the hardware being as new and the graphics driver failing to load (onboard graphics on a 5 year old board). It kept giving stack traces shortly after showing the login prompt. Was also fixed by adding nomodeset.